# Chrome Mobile loses theme color

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

While testing a website, I noticed a strange behavior of Chrome's theme color on Android.

When the website is loading initially, everything works fine and the theme color is applied correctly. However, after using a input field, Chrome loses the theme color. From now on, the  toolbar has the default color.

Does anybody know what is causing this problem?

[image: screen recording]

Here is the HTML I used for testing:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#0bc692">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input name="username" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input name="password" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

I have tested the website on a web server with TLS (with valid certificate). Everything works fine here. Is this related to not having TLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Chrome bug report.

See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1057772

It is a bug and exists since Chrome 70.0.3509.0.

The issue currently has a low priority because it only occurs when a webpage is served without TLS. In addition, there will be a new security indicator in a next release which will avoid the issue.